# android custom font attribute for widgets

Tags: android

I have some widgets and I'm trying to set custom fonts for them. This is my simple xml ui:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<ir.pishguy.makumarket.app.Libraries.internal.MDButton
    app:mdbutton_font="bnazanin"/>
</ir.pishguy.makumarket.app.Libraries.internal.MDButton>
```

This is my attribute for that:

```
<declare-styleable name="MDButton">
    <attr name="mdbutton_font">
        <enum name="consolas"    value="0"/>
        <enum name="times"  value="1"/>
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

and this is my custom MDButton class:

```
public MDButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MDButton_mdbutton_font);
    String str = a.getString(R.styleable.MDButton_mdbutton_font);
    switch (Integer.parseInt(str)) {
        case 0:
            str = "fonts/consolas.ttf";
            break;
        case 1:
            str = "fonts/times.ttf";
            break;
    }
    setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance(context).loadFont(str));
}
```

I get this error for `R.styleable.MDButton_mdbutton_font` in :

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MDButton_mdbutton_font,defStyleAttr,0);
```

**Error:**

```
Error:(37, 73) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
```

and after change it to :

```
new int[]{R.styleable.MDButton_mdbutton_font}
```

I get `NULL` for `str`. How do I set the custom font document in web. I don't see any document about this problem and in all of documents I don't see use `int[]` for `R.styleable.MDButton_mdbutton_font`. How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the name of an attribute instead of the name of a styleable. It should be this:

```
context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MDButton, defStyleAttr, 0);
```